# Session Login is not working

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have an admin login panel. I tried to log in with the correct data but it didn't give me access. The database is included with fns.php. Please help me out on what's wrong with this code.

I know about the 'session_is_registered' isn't up-to-date but, in the end, it didn't affect the result. So I've posted the initial code as I've got it.

```
<?
session_start();

include("fns.php");
include("header.php");
if((!@$password||!$login)&&!session_is_registered("admin"))
{

?> 
<center>
<b>Login here:</b>
<table  class=regform>
<tr><td><form name="login" method="get" action="index.php"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Login:</td><td> <input name="login" type="text"></td><br></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td> <input name="password" type="Password"></td><br><br></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="enter" type="submit" class=submitbutton  value="Verify"></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>

<?

}
else{
if (!session_is_registered("admin")){
db_connect();
$result=mysql_query("select password from admin where login='$login'");
$result=mysql_fetch_array(@$result);
if($password!=$result['password'] ||!$result)
{echo "Access denied";}
else{
session_register("admin");
$admin="admin";}}
if (session_is_registered("admin")){


display_admin_menu();

 } 
}

?>
<?
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: i see $login variable in your query, can you tell what its value, means how its getting the value

Comment: A side note: try **not** to use short open PHP tags `<?`, use instead `<?php`

Comment: @bodi0 its not a side note, its a good note, i did not even notice, Thanks

Comment: i have no clue where it come from

Comment: add this line after `db_connect();` `$login=$_POST['login']`; and tell us does it work

Comment: sorry i did not read your form method is get so add this `$login=$_GET['login']`; Thanks; and your form is submitting data to index.php; hope you are running your query in index.php. Thanks

Comment: well this is my index.php - remains the same

Comment: is adding $login=$_GET['login']; solve any thing ??

Comment: nope, i've added $login=$_GET['login']; right after db_connect(); - no changes

Comment: i will code my self this time and will come back Thanks, wait

Comment: i can not code my self, as my my localhost is not working, dear one last logical flaw may be or may be not. you dont need else, try after removing `else {` and removie the last line curly `}` braket as well

Comment: now it's just open for everyone - but i can work with this for the moment - and make a directory_password

Comment: does it work after removing the else statement??

Comment: if it does work after removing the else statement, let me know you dont need to create password for directory, it can me done

Comment: not fully working - i'm logged in but features don't work

Comment: acctually all - like personal details and more.. but i take a look at it later - to fix it - gotta buy food now

Comment: ok buy food, and post comment with this @ they will notify me, i will tell you what to do. Thanks

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 this would be great - im ready

Comment: dear not now as i have to just post a good comment, i will be back may 16 hours, i will have a look, the reason else was the problem, as your if statement. constructed like that, either your if gonna work or else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the '$login' variable.
Also - Fetching the password is wrong, you should check if a user exists with these credentials, not fetching the password and then matching it to the post.

```
<?Php
session_start();

include("fns.php");
include("header.php");
if((!isset($_POST)&&!session_is_registered("admin"))
{

?> 
<center>
<b>Login here:</b>
<table  class=regform>
<tr><td><form name="login" method="get" action="index.php"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Login:</td><td> <input name="login" type="text"></td><br></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td> <input name="password" type="Password"></td><br><br></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="enter" type="submit" class=submitbutton  value="Verify"></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>

<?Php

}
else{
if (!session_is_registered("admin")){
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']); 
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
db_connect();
$result=mysql_query("select * from admin where login='$login' AND password = '$password'");
$result=mysql_fetch_array(@$result);
if(!$result)
{echo "Access denied";}
else{
session_register("admin");
$admin="admin";}}
if (session_is_registered("admin")){


display_admin_menu();

 } 
}

include("footer.php");
?>
```